# position element relative to responsive/scaling image

Tags: html, css

I'd like to position a html element relative to a responsive/scaling image, so for example a point is always in the same place on the image regardless of how the image is scaled, in this example I'd like to keep the dot always on her eye regardless of the size of the viewport. Is this even possible?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img {
  background-image: url("https://www.esquireme.com/public/images/2019/12/18/Kendall-Jenner-Best-Model-(3).jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom;
  0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">
    <div class="dot">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3knzrq4w/1/

Comment: Do you want the HTML element to scale along with the image? Also is using a little Javascript acceptable?

Comment: If Javascript is the only way yes @AHaworth, the HTML element shouldn't scale no.

Comment: Yes it can be done but requires a bit more arithmetic than CSS alone can manage so we need JS. Basically to emulate the calculation that 'cover' in CSS would be doing.

Answer (score 2):

We need to work out the % distances of the eye from the edge of the 'new' image. The new image is the one created by the CSS cover setting. This cuts off either the top/bottom or sides of the image so that what is left completely covers the element without distortion.

[image]

[image]

As the head is fairly near to the center of the image we can probably be sure that the eye will always be seen, but looking at these two scenarios we see that the image created by cover (the part of the image left, outlined in the black rectangle) has a different aspect ratio from the original so the % distance of one of left or top of the eye will change, the other remains as on the original.

So we need to do a bit of arithmetic to calculate what the new % offsets of the HTML element should be.

Note that in this snippet the .img element is removed and the background put onto the container as .img didn't seem necessary just to hold a background.

```js
const originalPercentLeft = 40; // relative to the original image - as given in the question
const originalPercentTop = 29; // I remeasured as 34 put the dot too far down the face
const imgW = 1000; // for this particular image - in general would load the img then find its aspect ratio
const imgH = 667;

function setup() {
let percentLeft = originalPercentLeft;
let percentTop = originalPercentTop;

const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const containerW = container.offsetWidth;
const containerH = container.offsetHeight;
const imgAspectRatio = imgW / imgH;
const containerAspectRatio = containerW / containerH;

if (imgAspectRatio > containerAspectRatio ) { //as in the first picture
  const newImgW = imgH * containerAspectRatio;
  percentLeft = 100 * ( (imgW * percentLeft)/100 - (imgW - newImgW)/2 )/newImgW;
}
else { //as in the second picture
  const newImgH = imgW / containerAspectRatio;
  percentTop = 100 * ( (imgH * percentTop)/100 - (imgH - newImgH)/2 )/newImgH;
}
// now we can position the HTML element;
const dot = document.querySelector('.dot');
dot.style.left = percentLeft + '%';
dot.style.top = percentTop + '%';
}
window.onresize = setup;
setup();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://www.esquireme.com/public/images/2019/12/18/Kendall-Jenner-Best-Model-(3).jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="dot">
    </div>
</div>
```