# How to add a css animation on a specific point in a picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have 2 pictures. The first one is the one i'll be using for my website. The second one is the one I manually made to find a fixed points. However, my problem is that I'm not sure how to add my css animation to those specific locations.

I'm stuck on where to go from here because the dots keep changing locations based on the Screen size or Browser size. So I need it to be responsive that it looks exactly the same for all browsers.

the first picture
[image]

the second picture (where the dots needs to be)
[image]

Here are the code I have currently

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    #bg {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      /* Preserve aspet ratio */
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

  </style>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LpQXJfW.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
</body>

</html>
```

The dot animation

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #cfd9df;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .circle {
            background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
            border-radius: 50%;
            animation: pulse-red 1.9s infinite;
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
        }


        @keyframes pulse-red {
            0% {
                transform: scale(0.9);
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
            }
            
            80% {
                transform: scale(1);
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 11px rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
            }
            
            100% {
                transform: scale(0.9);
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
            }
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now above were just the backbone of my goal. Then I did the following, which illustrates what i'm trying to do. But it's not responsive, and worst of all you have to manually drag and drop the point.

```js
function placeDiv(x_pos, y_pos) {
  var d = document.querySelector('.circle');
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = x_pos + 'px';
  d.style.top = y_pos + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  placeDiv(e.clientX, e.clientY);
});
```

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse-red 1.9s infinite;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

@keyframes pulse-red {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 11px rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/52dLf1W.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</body>
```

How do I add my pulsing animation (4 of them) on top of my picture so that it looks exactly the same on every screen size?

Comment: Are your image element and your circle element both appended to the body? Can you show the final HTML file with both elements?

Comment: @sychordCoder if you look at the second page that has dots in them, that is what I want my final code to look like

Comment: You need to use % offsets and to compensate for the image changing how much is shown depending on screen size. I think this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67422567/position-element-relative-to-responsive-scaling-image/67445691#67445691 should help you but let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think this could work is to keep the aspect ratio of the image. That or convert to base64 and highlight the areas you want by pixel.

Try this out

```js
let imageBG = document.getElementById("bg");
let container = document.getElementById("container");
let imageBGBounds = imageBG.getBoundingClientRect();
let circle = document.getElementById("circle")
let circleBounds = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
window.onload = function() { sizeImage() }
window.addEventListener("resize", () => { sizeImage() });
  
function sizeImage() {
  let imageBGBounds = imageBG.getBoundingClientRect();
  let circleBounds = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
  let ratio = 320/853;
  let width = window.innerWidth;
  let height = width * ratio;
  imageBG.style.width = width+'px';
  container.style.width = width+'px';
  imageBG.style.height = height+"px";
  container.style.height = height+"px";
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #cfd9df;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
 /* width: $width;
  height: $height;*/
}
#bg {
  position: absolute;
 /* width: $width;
  height: $height;*/
}
#circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60%;
  top: 60%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse-red 1.9s infinite;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes pulse-red {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  }

  80% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 11px rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/LpQXJfW.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
<div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```